# Make an old commit + changes the new master

Tags: git, github

So I checked out a commit from 3:00 p.m. yesterday I want to make it the new master, effectively ignoring all commits that happened after 3:00 p.m.

How do I do this?

Comment: What is your code so far, and what did you try?

Comment: `git commit master` But it says: 
`error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the commit you want to make the new master has commit sha `abcdefg`, then you can use this (while having your `master` branch checked out):

```
git reset --hard abcdefg
```

This will change the branch pointer for `master` to point to commit `abcdefg`, effectively making it the new top commit for the `master` branch.

You can read more about [`reset` at the official Git documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset).